# LCD TFT Voltages

Tags: lcd, tft

I'm making a board for a **WF101-1024600AL#Z01B-FC** TFT LCD.
I don't understand (simply the datasheet doesn't help) what I have to do with **VGH, VGL** and **AVDD**. 
[image: LCD's max absolut ratings]

Should I provide these voltages externaly or that pins are just outputs?

Thanks in advance, 
Gabriele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen in other TFT display datasheets it's the voltages used to drive the gate of the pixels. Supply the VGH and VGL pins with the typical voltage.

Edit: As for AVDD, that's the positive supply voltage for the analog circuit.